# find N intersection points(closest points) among M lines

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, 3d, machine-learning, least-squares

There is algorithm problem, I have N  (around 10000) 3D  Lines, and I know there are around 20 (maybe 21, or 22) intersection points among these lines (the point may not exactly on the lines). Are there any efficient algorithm to solve this problem. My thought is calculate intersection point (or closest points) for any of two lines. Then use K mean to calculate the center of these cloud points.

Comment: Do you have any more information about the system than just equations of all the lines? For example, limits for the region where the lines may intersect? Even if not, it may be useful to find reasonable limits on that region, as you can divide into sections so that lines that don't cross sections cannot intersect. This can allow you to divide up the lines in groups that might intersect each other without having to test every pair of lines separately.

Comment: Yes, I know the limits of these region. I have a rectangle box to confine all intersection points. So, I can eliminate all intersection happen out of the regions.

Comment: @PaulSinclair But the only problem is if I need to check all possible solution, my computing cost is O(M^2)

Comment: I'm not talking about skipping solutions. I'm pointing out a way to eliminate significant numbers of pairs as having **no** intersection without having to check each pair individually. Cut your rectangle with a plane. All lines that do not intersect the plane inside the rectangle can be divided into two groups based on which side of the plane they are on. No pairs of lines with one line from each group will have an intersection, so you can eliminate all such pairs without testing them indiviually.